# Difference between $.noConflict, $.noConflict(true) and $.noConflict(false)

Tags: jquery

I have seen people use  `$.noConflict`, `$.noConflict(true)` and `$.noConflict(false)`. I want to know the difference between these statements.

Comment: I'm surprised a google search turned up nothing....

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since many library's use `$` to hold functions like jquery. `$.noConflict` pretty much re-inits jquery so if any library's did use `$` jquery will make sure it is using `$`. 
by adding true it does the exact same thing on a global scope